# C++ concept to match an alternative of a std::variant (but that also works with types inherited from std::variant)

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++23

I use a lot of `std::variant`s. I have this trusty helper concept that matches alternatives of a specific variant type:

```
template<typename alternative_type, typename variant_type>
struct alternative_c_impl {
   static_assert(false, "can't use is_alternative<> with a non-variant"); // legal in C++23
};
template<typename alternative_type, typename... variant_alternatives>
struct alternative_c_impl<alternative_type, std::variant<variant_alternatives...>>
   : std::disjunction<std::is_same<alternative_type, variant_alternatives>...>
{};
template<typename alternative_type, typename variant_type>
concept alternative_c = alternative_c_impl<alternative_type, variant_type>::value;

auto main() -> int
{
   using simple_variant = std::variant<int, float>;
   static_assert(alternative_c<int, simple_variant>);
   static_assert(alternative_c<std::string, simple_variant> == false);
}
```

However in C++23, we can now have types derived from `std::variant`. For such, this approach fails expectedly with the initial `static_assert`. My template skills got a little rusty and I'm having trouble expanding this to work with such a type. I guess it somehow involves `std::derived_from`. Speaking in code, I want a `mystery_c` concept that works analogously:

```
struct derived_var : std::variant<int, float>
{
   
};

auto main() -> int
{
   static_assert(mystery_c<int, derived_var>);
   static_assert(mystery_c<std::string, derived_var> == false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a concept that attempts to deduce an instantiation of `std::variant` from an instance of the `TVariant` as a function parameter, allowing base-class conversion, and then use a fold expression to test `TAlternative` against each type in the template parameter pack deduced for the instantiation:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

namespace detail {

template <class... Ts>
std::variant<Ts...> to_variant(const std::variant<Ts...> &);

template <class TAlternative, class TVariant>
inline constexpr bool is_alternative_v = false;

template <class TAlternative, class... Ts>
inline constexpr bool is_alternative_v<TAlternative, std::variant<Ts...>> =
    (... or std::is_same_v<TAlternative, Ts>);

}  // namespace detail

template <class TAlternative, class TVariant>
concept alternative_c = requires(TVariant var) {
  requires detail::is_alternative_v<TAlternative,
                                    decltype(detail::to_variant(var))>;
};
```

Since this approach doesn't require support for lambdas in unevaluated contexts, it will work with all compilers that support C++20 concepts, starting with Clang 10, GCC 10, and MSVC 19.30:

https://godbolt.org/z/9c7qzo1sd

Comment: Would suggest `to_variant` taking by `const&` just to avoid this failing when the variant itself isn't copyable.

Comment: @Barry `std::variant` is copyable per the specification. Even if the copy constructor is deleted on the derived class, this still works.

Comment: [It does not work](https://godbolt.org/z/6zGec5se3), unless you [add the const&](https://godbolt.org/z/bGdYz93q3).

Comment: @Barry ah I misunderstood, I thought you were talking about user-defined constructors in the derived class, not conditionally defined constructors in `std::variant`, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Nested `requires` can be eliminated via `std::declval<const TVariant&>()`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I prefer the `requires` syntax, thanks. For me its a preference of language feature vs. library feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a concept to require that a lambda with specific constraints be a valid expression:

```
template<class T, typename Var>
concept alternative_c = requires (const Var& var) { 
  []<typename... Args>
    requires (std::same_as<T, Args> || ...) 
      (const std::variant<Args...>&){ } (var);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cMdMY4qoe)

The parameter part requires `Var` to be inherited from `variant`, and the constraint part requires `T` to be one of its alternatives.